# Encryption without decryption

Tags: linux, encryption

I am struck in a problem as that I have some private data. I need to give the data to someone where they need to apply some logic on the encrypted data that is given. The objective here is that they need not to be able to decrypt and apply the logic as well. Is there any way to achieve this. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of data is it and what kind of logic third party is going to apply?

Comment: "And they can't apply the logic as well"? You said you want them to apply the logic.

Comment: @PanJanek That is actually the financial data which will be used for data mining and analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe anonymization of data will be sufficient? For example if the numbers represent transactions, you could change all the names of contractors, people, companies, branches and so on to GUIDS, send the data for analysis, and connect the GUIDS with names in the incoming results on your side - of course somebody with industry knowledge could guess more or less what's going on anyway, but at least you won't expose subject's data.

Comment: Thanks PanJanek that sounds great provided exposing transactions are not an issue without a source or subject.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

Comment: Thanks ninjagecko. That is a good option. I am looking into your solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you keep your encryption keys to yourself, no one else will be able to decrypt the data.